# Django tables-import error

Tags: django-views

i am having an import error django_tables.
Could not import ikapp.views.admin. Error was: No module named django_tables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ikapp.views.admin` requires `django-tables`. Unfortunately it's not possible to tell which version/fork it requires, but it's likely to be either:

- https://github.com/miracle2k/django-tables
- https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2

Answer (score 0):

django_tables requires that you actually be running within the django-"primed" python environment. You can access this by going to your project's directory and typing

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then you can import django_tables with no problems.
For further info, take a look at the following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/